# How do I interupt an (infinite) stream?

Tags: elixir, twitter-streaming-api

I'm working with the [ExTwitter](https://github.com/parroty/extwitter) library and would like to be able to occasionally kill a call to the streaming API to change parameters.

My current code looks something like this:

```
for tweet <- ExTwitter.stream_filter(track: terms) do
    process_tweet tweet
end
```

Is there anything I could do to indicate that I don't want any more messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for trying out. I could confirm the method Chris indicated works. As an alternative approach, I put one trial as an API method call in the following (though I'm not confident how to take infinite stream properly yet).

https://github.com/parroty/extwitter/issues/2

Comment: Marking this as correct, as you're the library author and this will become official.

Answer (score 5):

You can throw an exception and catch it:

```
try do
  for tweet <- ExTwitter.stream_filter(track: terms) do
    process_tweet tweet
    if logic_to_determine_halt?, do: throw :halt
  end
catch 
  :halt -> #finished
end
```